# How to specify a TemplateBinding command in code?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following xaml, specifically it has a button command, which uses a `TemplateBinding` to access a ViewModel command.

```
<ContentView
    x:Class="OurApp.Controls.CustomPopupWrapper" >
    <ContentView.ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackLayout>

              <Button
Command="{TemplateBinding Parent.BindingContext.ClosePopupAsyncCommand}" />

           </StackLayout>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentView.ControlTemplate>
</ContentView>
```

**How can I specify the `TemplateBinding` command in code?**

I would like to be able to add a condition to only use the `TemplateBinding` command as a default value and use a `BindableProperty` parameter to pass other commands.

I can't seem to find any sources on the web that show how to specify a `TemplateBinding` with a command in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code behind should be something like this:

```
public void test()
{


    Button btn = new Button();
    TemplateBinding templateBinding = new TemplateBinding("ClosePopupAsyncCommand");

    btn.BindingContext = myViewModel;

    btn.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, templateBinding);
}
```

Refer: [BindableObject.SetBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableobject.setbinding?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_BindableObject_SetBinding_Xamarin_Forms_BindableProperty_Xamarin_Forms_BindingBase_) [TemplateBinding Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.templatebinding?view=xamarin-forms)

Comment: Thanks... however I'm getting a `Specified cast is not valid` error from the SetBiding line.

Comment: To be clear I used "ClosePopupAsyncCommand" and no error was created but the button didn't work... using "Parent.BindingContext.ClosePopupAsyncCommand" caused the error.

Comment: You should use ClosePopupAsyncCommand and did you set correct binding context to btn?

Comment: I think with the button being in a ControlTemplate has complicated things. I’m guessing under normal circumstances this would have worked.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your point. You just need to set the right BindingContext to the btn and it will work I think.